# How do you move a sprite completely offscreen?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

My sprite moves to the left, as it should but it stops moving and does not go offscreen, as I want it to. It's as if there is an invisible wall.

I have tried https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfIOPWuUjn8.

In the video, the person's sprite completely moves off the screen but mine doesn't.

```
public Sprite Pokemon_0;
public Sprite Pokemon_1; 

void Update()
        {
        if (transform.position.x >= -40) 
        {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_0;
            transform.Translate(-1f,0f,0f);
        }
```

I am working on the sprite moving off the screen on the left, and a different sprite appearing from the right and moving to the centre of the screen. The code doesn't include anything about the second sprite but that is why I have referred to the sprite in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling it to only move left  `if (transform.position.x >= -40)`.

So either change your camera so that x = -40 is outside of your screen, or decrease the value in the boolean expression to something lower than `-40` so that it moves further left until it stops moving, e.g.:

```
if (transform.position.x >= -80f) 
{
    transform.Translate(-1f,0f,0f);
}
```

Also, `GetComponent` is an expensive procedure, and you only need to set the sprite once, so you should create a `Start` method that does the sprite assignment.  This way, you don't waste time every frame getting the same component and assigning the sprite that's already assigned to it.

The `this.gameObject.` part is redundant, so you can get rid of that part as well:

```
Start()
{
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Pokemon_0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Ruzihm's answer, you can also try to use

```
if (GetComponent<Renderer>().isVisible) 
{
    transform.Translate(-1f,0f,0f);
}
```

instead of using a number such as "-40f" or "-80f", in this way you can be sure that the sprite will be off screen.

Comment: My understanding is that this may produce unexpected positive results during development if the renderer is in view of the scene editor's camera.